# Best way to update an element in a generic List

Tags: c#, generic-list

Suppose we have a class called Dog with two strings "Name" and "Id". Now suppose we have a list with 4 dogs in it. If you wanted to change the name of the Dog with the "Id" of "2" what would be the best way to do it?

```
Dog d1 = new Dog("Fluffy", "1");
Dog d2 = new Dog("Rex", "2");
Dog d3 = new Dog("Luna", "3");
Dog d4 = new Dog("Willie", "4");

List<Dog> AllDogs = new List<Dog>()
AllDogs.Add(d1);
AllDogs.Add(d2);
AllDogs.Add(d3);
AllDogs.Add(d4);
```

Comment: There are so many ways. *Define best*?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I thought that was the question?

Comment: @SemiDemented Best meaning? Best in what? Performance? Memory? Maintenance? Concise? or what? Best means little, you should be specific.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
AllDogs.First(d => d.Id == "2").Name = "some value";
```

However, a safer version of that might be this:

```
var dog = AllDogs.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == "2");
if (dog != null) { dog.Name = "some value"; }
```

Comment: Note that you can also just do `AllDogs.First(d => d.Id == "2").Name =`...

Comment: @ReedCopsey, thank you very much for that. A more concise way of getting at it!

Comment: This would work if you have one property to update. What if there are many properties and you want to replace the entire object in the list with a new one?

Comment: Why not use 
`var dog = AllDogs.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == "2");`
instead of
`var dog = AllDogs.Where(d => d.Id == "2").FirstOrDefault();`
?

Comment: @KotMatroskin, yep that's a better optimization. Edited.

Answer (score 7):

You could do:

```
var matchingDog = AllDogs.FirstOrDefault(dog => dog.Id == "2"));
```

This will return the matching dog, else it will return `null`.

You can then set the property like follows:

```
if (matchingDog != null)
    matchingDog.Name = "New Dog Name";
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` isn't really useful here.  If it returns "default", it'll raise a `NullReferenceException` when you try to set `Name`...

Comment: that means it really IS useful here because if you just use .first, you'll get an exception doing the select itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is sorted (as happens to be in the example) a binary search on index certainly works.

```
    public static Dog Find(List<Dog> AllDogs, string Id)
    {
        int p = 0;
        int n = AllDogs.Count;
        while (true)
        {
            int m = (n + p) / 2;
            Dog d = AllDogs[m];
            int r = string.Compare(Id, d.Id);
            if (r == 0)
                return d;
            if (m == p)
                return null;
            if (r < 0)
                n = m;
            if (r > 0)
                p = m;
        }
    }
```

Not sure what the LINQ version of this would be.

Comment: Why reinvent that. [List<T>.BinarySearch](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjMiZf1zMblAhXjQ98KHWYUCMwQFjAAegQIBRAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch&usg=AOvVaw2CwInMFi1iu3vXlCBu52yj) works great.