# How to edit list in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I would like to have an edit function in my program. I am creating a phone book wherein I use list in saving data (no database yet). I would like to have an edit function whenever i click an item in the list but I do not know how to do it.

This is my code for adding:

```
Person contact = new Person();
private ObservableCollection<Person> person = new ObservableCollection<Person>(); 
person.Add(new Person() 
    { 
        Name = contact.Name, 
        Contact = contact.Contact, 
        ImagePath = contact.ImagePath, 
        Gender = contact.Gender 
    });
```

I used selection changed when determining the selected item in the list. A help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You want to edit a record or you want add a new record?

Comment: Why not just add `contact`? `person.Add(contact);`

Comment: Explaining the setup and reasoning behind the entire process of creating, editing, deleting and updating records (especially when dealing with WPF and databinding) is a little bit steep for a single question / answer. You are on the right track by using an `ObservableCollection` though.

Comment: So you make the properties of that item observable and when you edit them in the UI, the backing fields will change too.

Comment: I want to edit a existing record. Not add another record. I already did the add, what I want to do now is edit an existing record

Comment: @Sarah the typical way to go about that in WPF is to create a separate control for editing the records. one that uses two-way bindings would be simplest to implement.
Bind the `datacontext` of that control to the `SelectedItem` property of your list, and you should be set to go

Comment: your question is not clear,do you want add a new record?

Answer (score 1):

You should add an ID to your list, it will make your life easier, anyway here's mine from my previous assignment.

```
var vPersonID = YourListGoesHere.Where(pID => pID.personID == id).FirstOrDefault()
if (vPersonID !=null)
{
 vPersonID.Name = "ganda mo po";
//etc etc.
}
```

more info here [Best way to update an element in a generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280986/best-way-to-update-an-element-in-a-generic-list) .

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `DataGrid` control to display and edit a collection of objects: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx

Set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to your `ObservableCollection<Person>` and double click in a cell to edit a value of a property of a `Person` object:

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> person = new ObservableCollection<Person>(); 
...
dataGrid.ItemsSource = person;
```

---

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" />
```